# How to find $z$-intercept of vector equation

Tags: calculus, vector-spaces

How do I find the $z$-intercept of the vector equation $\left<x,y,z\right> = (6, -2, -3) + t \left<3,-1,-2\right>$

I am so lost, do I set $x$ and $y$ equal to zero, and solve for $z$?

I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: What do you mean "$\;z-$ intercept " ? Where does that line intersects the $\;z-$ axis ? For that you need that the $\;x,y\;$ coordinates equal zero...

Comment: you say you have no idea, but you had it right,  so that implies you should feel more confident. better to make the odd mistake and be corrected than to feel helpless. however maybe your mathematical instinct correctly told you that there is no guarantee that a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$ will meet the $z$-axis at all. so the phrasing of the problem is poor. instead of "the intercept" it should have said "find the point where....meets the $z$-axis", which implies that such a point does, in this case, exist. I wish you well with your studies.

Comment: @DavidHolden haha thanks for the confidence, but I'm assuming if it meets the z-axis, it is in fact an intercept... Anyways thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 2):

find the value of t such that x(t)=y(t)=0.  then evaluate for z.

Comment: this line intercepts the z axis, all values along the z-axis have the coordinates (0,0,z).